# In notmuch search results, how to find which maildir contains each of the emails?

Tags: mutt

I am using `notmuch` with the mua `mutt` (actually, `neomutt`). When I perform a search, all matching mail is accessible via a special maildir which I can open in `mutt`. However, I have not found any way to display the actual maildir in which each of these emails is stored.

Technically, I see that `notmuch` creates a temporary maildir which contains dynamic links pointing to the mail files in their different maildirs. So the information is accessible through the path of these dynamic links, but this is not very convenient.

Ideally I would code a hook that can display the name of the folder either in the message index or when displaying message. But I am not even sure `mutt` has a sequence defined giving the file path of the message, `%b` for instance returns an empty string in the `notmuch` maildir. Any hint on how to code this?

[Note: this is a programming question following an unsuccessful question at SuperUser, https://superuser.com/questions/1254053/in-notmuch-search-results-which-maildir-contains-each-of-the-emails, which was aiming at finding a user solution in the software]

Comment: "Technically, I see that notmuch creates a temporary maildir which contains dynamic links pointing to the mail files in their different maildirs." The notmuch core does nothing of the sort. That's possibly the notmuch-mutt integration script. But why would you be using the script since neomutt can interface with notmuch natively using the libnotmuch API?

Comment: PS. You can use notmuch on the command line to get the information directly: notmuch search --output=files <search-terms>

Comment: @Jani thanks or your messages. I'll check my install in case there's a clash between neomutt and notmuch-mutt which I had installed previously.

Comment: I've read your questions. But from none of them I didn't catch what is the exact goal you want to achieve? Do you just want to see in mutt/neomutt the folder name? Or is that more about message deletion or being able to distinguish between postponed and sent messages as you mentioned in the other question?

Comment: @JakubJindra Thanks for reviving this question. Well, any progress would be welcome: just telling me which folder contains the e-mail would be good, being able to switch to that folder with the selected email highlighted would be great. I am not sure whether deleting from the search result folder would be a good idea, would raise issues? In the other post, I was mentioning the fact that it was really a user-perspective danger to see in search results emails postponed along with those actually sent, without being able to know to which category any of them belong. But that was just an example.

Comment: @Joce see my answer to very similar question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501852/85046